# How can I embed HTML tags into a JSON object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple hash containing a description:

```
simple_hash = { "description" => "<p>This is my description.</p>" }
```

I need write this out to a file. In the file, this hash needs to be represented as JSON:

```
simple_hash.to_json
```

But this is what I'm actually getting:

```
"{\"description\":\"\\u003cp\\u003eThis is my description.\\u003c/p\\u003e\"}"
```

How do I stop `to_json` from doing that to my HTML tags?

Comment: you don't, it's doing the right thing and encoding UTF-8 characters.  from_json will read it in just fine.

Comment: embedding a format into another is a recipe for a failure unless you can prove otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_json` is doing the safe thing encoding the HTML.

If you are certain that it is safe, you can easily decode with Rails' `JSON.parse`

```
>> JSON.parse "{\"desc\":\"\\u003cp\\u003eThis is my description.\\u003c/p\\u003e\"}"
=> {"desc"=>"<p>This is my description.</p>"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this:

```
def json_template(id)
  ###################
  # Method to create the json templates
  ###################
  File.open("test_dir/temp_file.json", 'w'){|i|
    templ = %Q<{
  "id": "#{Random.rand(20)}#{Random.rand(20)}",
  "version": 1.0.1.1,
  "service": "ftp",
  "os": "linux"
  }>
    i.write(templ)
  }
end
```